# return several fields using terms aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

With this kind of aggregation:

```
  "some_agg":{  
     "terms":{  
        "size":10,
        "field":"name.keyword"
     },
     "aggs":{  
        "bucket_sort_agg":{  
           "bucket_sort":{  
              "sort":[  
                 {  
                    "_count":{  
                       "order":"desc"
                    }
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

I receive something like:

```
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "some name",
      "doc_count": 2035
    },
    {
      "key": "other name",
      "doc_count": 1017
    },
    {
```

If the document has other fields like email, is it possible to receive also that field? without using a nested aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregations do not return documents, they aggregate them. The 2035 documents that have `name: some name` might have completely different values for other fields.

If you want, you can add other `terms` sub-aggregations on other fields to split the 2035 documents into more finer buckets.

Eventually, you can add a `top_hits` sub-aggregation in order to return the hits (i.e. the real documents) for each sub-sub-sub-bucket.

For instance:

```
"some_agg":{  
     "terms":{  
        "size":10,
        "field":"name.keyword"
     },
     "aggs":{  
        "another_field": {                <--- split on another field
          "terms": {
            "field": "another_field"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "hits": {                     <--- show all the hits for each sub-bucket
              "top_hits": {}
            }
          }
        },
        "bucket_sort_agg":{  
           "bucket_sort":{  
              "sort":[  
                 {  
                    "_count":{  
                       "order":"desc"
                    }
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
     }
  }
```